# Firstobjects easyzlib does not work on RedHat 4 Linux

Tags: c

I have tried hard to get this file working on Linux, but I am unable.
What is the issue I am unable to understand?  It is not writing the proper header.

If any one has any idea, please let me know.

Comment: There is absolutely no information here for us to try and help you.  What are the errors you are getting?  What is the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Some suggestions that would help your question - a link (URL) to the library (where does it come from?), and a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do at the point of failure (run the `configure` script?), and what the detailed error message is (the first one).  This will help you get the answers quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Easy zlib is available from [FirstObject](http://www.firstobject.com/easy-zlib-c++-xml-compression.htm) and comes as a simple zip file containing a C source file (about 330 KiB) and a header file (just over 3 KiB) which extract into the current directory.   There is no configuration file, makefile or anything.

On MacOS X (10.6.6) with GCC (4.5.2), it compiles to an object file (about 86 KiB) trivially:

```
gcc -c easyzlib.c
```

How you package it from there seems to be up to you.

- You could simply use the source code in your project directory, and compile it as just another object file that is part of your system.
- Alternatively, you could compile it into a shared object and install it in an appropriate location (`/usr/local/lib`, perhaps) and place the header in the appropriate place (`/usr/local/include`).  Then you'd need to make sure the compiler looks in those places for the files.  At a pinch (though I don't recommend it) you could install them into `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include`, in which case there'd be no flags to add because the compiler looks there anyway.  If you do 32-bit and 64-bit compilations, or if you want shared and static libraries, or other such complications, then you need to know a lot about your build system.

Unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise, I suggest you treat it as local source to your project.  In the short term, that is least painful.  If you use it in many projects (remembering that computers count zero, one, many), then look into installing it once.